# Joomla External JTable connection

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a database I need to connect to remotely that is different then the Joomla database.

I can do this easily within other models but JModelAdmin is giving some issues as it seems to require JTable to function.

I have attempted to override the JTable instance to use my external database instead, however it does not seem to want to work and gets an error in "reset". My guess is JTable requires access to the core Joomla tables as well.

Is there any easy way to do this? Or is overriding the core the only option?

EDIT:
To clarify I can get Joomla to connect to the database and run queries. The only problem is that JTable refuses to initialize properly with an external database.

Here is my constructor in my model:

```
function __construct($config = array()){
    $config['dbo'] = TireApiHelper::tireAPIDB();
    parent::__construct($config);
}
```

This works in my *list* model but not my *admin* model. my *list* model has no need for a table class, however the controller needs to use the *admin* model to publish/unpublish, this is where the issue is. Even though JTable uses the currently set DB instance, it will return false with no Joomla error (according to code I should see a joomla error if `$table` returns false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can achieve this, but the key point is to create a new database object. You can find the instructions on how to do that [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Connecting_to_an_external_database). Once you have this object you could:

1. set your JTable class extension to use it via constructor or using the `setDBO(...)` method. See [this](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Platform/Table/JTable.html).
2. choose to use this object and a query object without any JTable, like is explained in the [Documentation site](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase/2.5).

Cheers.

Comment: I guess i should expand, I have no problem with the connection, however JTable refuses to use the new database and after pouring through 2000+ lines of code from modeadmin.php, modelform.php, model.php and table.php I see no reason for it not to work. Unless it does not like InnoDB?

Comment: It has no problem with InnoDB, what does exactly your error say?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function reset() on a non-object in /../component/modeladmin.php on line 850 
This tells me that $table returned false, but there is no joomla error.

Comment: It looks like it's not finding your JTable class extension. You should start by making sure you have the type and prefix right. If it doesn't work, make sure the database table is correct in the constructor (I guess your other database doesn't use the joomla prefix) and check also the field you specify there as primary key.

Comment: Yes I just figured it out and yes that is the answer (found out just before I read this). Thank you I will mark yous as the answer. The problem stems from the table class not being like other classes in Joomla that the Table portion of the prefix is automatic.

Comment: You need to creat a new connection and define the prefix there rather than using the default from jConfig.